# Error in input genes for GSEA analysis with ClusterProfiler

Tags: r, macos, rna-seq

I want to perform GSEA analysis on my DESeq2 results, but unfortunately, it does not work as it did (2 months ago), see error that follows after the code (at the bottom). I am 100% sure the data I am using is human. Do you know what causes this error?

Many thanks in advance!

Error:
preparing geneSet collections...
--> Expected input gene ID: BAX,KDM1A,VPS54,ENKUR,H2BC1,SLC19A1
Error in check_gene_id(geneList, geneSets) :
--> No gene can be mapped....

```
#Order the genes from DESeq2 analysis (= res)
res.df <- as.data.frame(res)
res.df <- na.omit(res.df)
res.ordered <- res.df[order(-res.df$stat),]
gene_list_GSEA <- res.ordered$stat

#GSE analysis 
gse <- gseGO(gene_list_GSEA, 
             ont ="ALL", 
             keyType = "SYMBOL", 
             OrgDb = "org.Hs.eg.db",
            # nPerm = 10000, 
             minGSSize = 3, 
             maxGSSize = 800, 
             pvalueCutoff = 0.05, 
             verbose = TRUE
             )
```

Comment: According to the [source code for the gseGO function](https://rdrr.io/bioc/clusterProfiler/src/R/gseAnalyzer.R), `keyType = "SYMBOL"` isn't an option; perhaps try `keyType = "ncbi-geneid"`?

Comment: Check out the examples in the online book: [Chapter 6 GO enrichment analysis | Biomedical Knowledge Mining using GOSemSim and clusterProfiler](https://yulab-smu.top/biomedical-knowledge-mining-book/clusterprofiler-go.html?q=gsego#go-gene-set-enrichment-analysis)

In the example, they use a descending numeric vector of fold changes (that's your preranked list for gene set enrichment analysis), where the `names()` of the vector are the entrez ID's.

Comment: And check out `AnnotationDbi::select()` or `AnnotationDbi::mapIds()` for converting your gene symbols to ENTREZID's using the same `org.Hs.eg.db` used in the `gseGO()` function.